# cookie path maybe? cookie not being set

Tags: php, cookies, http-headers

im having problems setting this `cookie`,
maybe it might be a path error im not sure just started playing with `cookies` yesterday
php code:

```
setcookie(md5('View-live-ad'),$_GET[md5('ad')],3600,'/');
sleep(1);
header('location: ../apo/');
```

but the cookie is not getting set.
im just trying hide the URL at all times (security attempt)

Answer (score 1):

You are expiring it in the past (3600 sec after the UNIX epoch, to be precise), which causes it to expire immediately.  Instead of `3600`, use `time() + 3600` to set its expiry 3600 sec from now:

```
setcookie(md5('View-live-ad'),$_GET[md5('ad')], time() + 3600 ,'/');
```